# UISwitch broken on / off animation while animating 'onTintColor'

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, uiviewanimation, ios-animations

I want to animate the 'on' color of a UISwitch AND keep it interactable, with no compromise to it's on / off animation. Here's what I tried:

1. UIView's animate with duration method doesn't work because well...it
   shouldn't, 'onTintColor' isn't listed as an animatable property of
   UIView. Fine.

   ```
   mySwitch.onTintColor = UIColor.green

   UIView.animate(withDuration: 10) {
       mySwitch.onTintColor = UIColor.red
   }
   ```
2. Next. UIView's transition with view method gives sort of the correct visual behaviour however when interacting with the switch the default on / off animation is compromised (see GIF).

   ```
   UIView.transition(with: mySwitch, duration: 10, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve, .allowUserInteraction], animations: { 
       mySwitch.onTintColor = UIColor.red
   }) { completed in
   }
   ```
3. CATransition gives the same behaviour as no. 2 (see GIF).

   ```
   var transition = CATransition()
   transition.type = kCATransitionFade
   transition.duration = 10
   mySwitch.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
   mySwitch.onTintColor = UIColor.red
   ```

[via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/N2vRjEfqKYSaY)

Anyone have any ideas how I can animate the 'onTintColor' without affecting the default on / off animation?

Is the only way of doing this properly going to be to create a custom switch?

Answer (score 3):

By default user interaction is disabled during animations. Try using the longer form of UIView animations,

`animate(withDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)`, and pass in options of `.allowUserInteraction`

Comment: thanks for that suggestion. Passing that option to transition with view does what it says which is great but it also effects the switch's default on / off animation. Please see my edit and linked GIF :)